# angular style sheet for table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I followed Angular material tutorial for displaying table of records.
https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

As per the tutorial, it is using **class="mat-elevation-z8"** style sheet. where I can get more information on different style sheets. I am looking for excel kind of row and column display. Any Help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/guide/elevation

Answer (score 2):

The mat-elevation-z# in material indicates the relative distance of 2 surfaces in the z-axis. So it is very heavily used for box shadowing so the controls look like they are floating in 3-dimensions.

All of these styles are included in the pre built themes that ship with angular material. Below is the link that explains how to use prebuilt themes.

This is what `mat-elevation-z8` translates to in their css.

[image]

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme

Comment: Can you mark it as answer if it answered your question please.